# C4244 level 4 warning on compound addition assignment, but not on sum and assignment

Tags: c++, c, compiler-warnings, compound-operator

In MSVS 2005, The following C code generates one warning:

```
int main() {
    short a = 0;
    a += a; // C4244 (level 4)
    a = a + a; // OK
}
```

The warning message is:

```
warning C4244: '+=' : conversion from 'int' to 'short', possible loss of data
```

The same goes for C++ code.

What is the difference between the two statements? I have heard, but could not find any reference to any C or C++ standard, that the compound operator implicitly casts the right-hand expression to the left-hand side's type. But should the sum-and-assignment statement not do the same? I also suspected that it had to do with int promotion, but as I can see from the disassembly, this happens in both cases:

```
[...]
    a += a; // C4244 (level 4)
00411394  movsx       eax,word ptr [a] 
00411398  movsx       ecx,word ptr [a] 
0041139C  add         ecx,eax 
0041139E  mov         word ptr [a],cx 
    a = a + a; // OK
004113A2  movsx       eax,word ptr [a] 
004113A6  movsx       ecx,word ptr [a] 
004113AA  add         eax,ecx 
004113AC  mov         word ptr [a],ax 
[...]
```

Additionally, the warning does not appear in MSVS 2008 with warning level set to 4. So can I consider this a bug in VS 2005, that was fixed later, or is there some sense to the original warning? The documentation does not help me here.

Comment: What's the text of the warning? Funnily enough I suspect most of us don't know the MS codes off by heart.

Comment: Sorry, just edited to add the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bogus warning.

Warnings are supposed to warn you about code you wrote, not about intermediate operations.

The code you wrote does not work with any `int` - only intermediate operations do.

An inquiry about [a case almost identical to yours](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5cdbb2cb-df99-4774-a3ff-7427b31aa930/warning-4244-adding-2-ushorts-with-) in the Visual Studio Languages Forums is answered by Jonathan Caves - MSFT. His answer ends:

> "This is has been on our list of bugs to fix for quite a while -
>   unfortunately we always find more "important" bugs to fix so we never
>   get around to fixing this one - but someday we will."

Comment: Also, see this [bug report](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/344908/compiler-option-wall-turns-error-c4244-conversion-from-int-to-char-into-warning-c4242-conversion-from-int-to-char-possible-loss-of-data).